# Embed an http server in a long running python process

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

Using python 3. Lets say I am processing a loop around a large database query.  Effectively my loop around the result set cursor can be a billion iterations.

I'd like to give a user an ability to call out to an http server embedded in the same process that would give some statistics on the progress of the query.

So far I have tried this with IOLoop using Tornado http server.  The problem is that I have to basically transfer the control back to IOLoop on some number of rows to get the HTTP request to get serviced.  That seems wasteful.  Transferring that control has a price.  Tornado would let me support multiple connections, but I don't actually care for that - one connection is fine.

What I would prefer would be to simply interrupt the loop, service the HTTP request and resume.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is probably open to too many possiblities...but using tornado I've just started an instance on a thread.  Threading issues with python aside, it basically does what i want.